# Duplicate field within duplicate group magic fields

Tags: php, wordpress

i have a write panel in magic fields with a group that can be duplicated, within this is an image field that can be duplicated.

So far i have the code for the duplicate group but i'm a little stuck on how to display the duplicate field within this.

I'm using Magic Fields 1.6.2.1

My code for the duplicate group is

```
<?php
$gallerys = getGroupOrder('gallery_section_title');
foreach($gallerys as $gallery) {
?>

<?php echo get('gallery_section_title',$gallery);?>

<?php echo get('gallery_section_text',$gallery);?>
<?php echo get('gallery_section_image',$gallery);?>

<?php } ?>
```

This part is the part that needs to be duplicated with in the duplicate group

```
<?php echo get('gallery_section_image',$gallery);?>
```

I did a few searches but can't find anything that works.
Does anyone have any ideas how to implement this, i'm stumped.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've worked this out and the code below works for me, there a probably a better more efficient way of doing it, but this works.

```
<?php $groups = getGroupOrder('gallery_section_title'); 
    foreach($groups as $group) { ?>  

<?php echo get('gallery_section_title', $group); ?>
<?php echo get('gallery_section_text', $group); ?>

<?php $fields = get_field_duplicate('gallery_section_image',$group); 
foreach($fields as $field)
{ ?> 

<?php echo $field[o]; ?>    

<?php } ?>

<?php } ?>
```